# Writing a HashMap to database using Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am trying to write the values of hashmap to a database using Hibernate.

MY POJO class
package org.rahul;

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.MapKeyColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "hash")
public class HashMapExample {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @ElementCollection
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "key_key")
  @JoinTable(name = "example_attributes", joinColumns =
                                  @JoinColumn(name"example_id"))
  private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Map<String, String> getMap() {
    return map;
  }

  public void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
    this.map = map;
  }

}
```

Main Class

```
package org.rahul.hibernate;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.rahul.HashMapExample;

public class HashMapMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        String name = "Rahul";
        String company = "Memoir";

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(name, company);
        Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map1.put("XYZ", "ABC");

        HashMapExample hash = new HashMapExample();
        HashMapExample hash1 = new HashMapExample();

        // hash.setId(2);
        hash1.setMap(map);
        hash.setMap(map1);
        session.getTransaction();
        session.save(hash);
        session.save(hash1);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }
}
```

I expect to get the table with a column containing the key value pair but , the I get the key values as different columns .

```
example_attribut table description : 
  CREATE TABLE `example_attributes` 
  ( 
     `example_id` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
     `map`        VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `key_key`    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`example_id`, `key_key`), 
     KEY `fkea50c74c5cd44e54` (`example_id`), 
     CONSTRAINT `fkea50c74c5cd44e54` FOREIGN KEY (`example_id`) REFERENCES 
     `hash` (`id`) 
  ) 
engine=innodb 
DEFAULT charset=utf8
```

hash table description :

```
CREATE TABLE `hash` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Why am I unable to describe the fields map and key_key as  hashmap ?I want them to be in a single field like key value pairs. can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there a couple ways to go about doing this.  You can persist a json string to your database that represents the key/value pairs.  **do not use json if you need to query against it as of 2013**

```
{key: 'myKey', values:[{'1'},{'2'},{'3'}]}
```

you can persist the java object to a blob (binary object).

```
id number,
map blob
```

This will allow you to store the data in one column.  I recommend the json string as it will not force you into using java for the rest of your life and others can also use your data.

Comment: @Newbie before I do that, do you plan on querying against this data?  The map data that is?

Comment: Yes, I will try to query the column that has both key and value. Can we do that ?

Comment: @Newbie that makes this different and the suggestion of storing json goes out the window.  You will need to store it as a blob if I am not mistaken.

Comment: How can I store it as a blob?

Comment: Help me with two things . Using a json to update the table and using a blob to update the table and retrieve the elements